# Can an OR gate be made using 2 XOR and 1 and gate?

Tags: logic-gates

[image]

Hello i was wondering if an OR gate can be made using 2 XOR gates and 1 AND gate.
as i got this question in one of my exams a few days ago.

Comment: Make a truth table. You'll answer your own question.

Comment: In this case, the AND-plus-XOR circuit is NOT equivalent to the OR gate. Note the third input coming from C!

Comment: @TomCarpenter make a truth table for the whole circuit or only for the OR gate?

Comment: The whole circuit.